# Ошибка 404 после перезагрузки страницы, Vue-router

Tags: vue.js, http-status-code-404, vue-router, error404

В dev режиме всё работает очень хорошо, но как только создаёться продакт версия приложения, всё идёт не так. При переходе на страницы с помошью v-link всё работает хорошо. А вот после перезагрузки этой же страницы браузер сообщает об ошибке 404.
Вопрос - как добиться того, чтоб браузер мог отображать любые существующие страницы по ссылке. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А продакт версия где хранится? Сервер настроен корректно?

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Только что именно об этом узнал, но нет. С сервером я работать умею плохо. Если не трудно, подскажите как перенаправить всё в СПА без лишних заморочек. Код PHP или Python был бы очень понятен.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ. Всё кроеться в файле .htaccess, где в самом верху просто нужно добавить:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://example-domain.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

В доке роутера описана эта проблема и ее решение с помощью конфигурации сервера (примеры под разные сервера имеются).

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations